# Pass object via ajax to Controller is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying pass a object to a controller, but in debug when i check data, the object arrive null. I already try to many things, but never get success.

Ajax:

```
   function filtro() {


    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var idade = document.getElementById("idade").value;
    var dataCriacao = document.getElementById("data-criacao").value;
    var dataInicio = document.getElementById("data-inicio").value;
    var dataFim = document.getElementById("data-fim").value;
    var tipo = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
    var ativo = document.getElementById("ativo").checked;

    var filtro = {
        IdadeText: idade,
        Nome: nome,
        DataDestaqueInicio: dataInicio,
        DataDestaqueFim: dataFim,
        DataAnuncioCriacao: dataCriacao,
        Ativo: ativo,
        Tipo: tipo,
    };
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Anuncios", "Admin")',
        data: filtro,
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        success: function (result) {
        }
    })
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Anuncios(FiltroAnuncioDTO filtro,int pg = 1)
{

    return Json("ok");
}
```

the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you pass the `pg` to API? Through request body, URL param, query string? Based on your jquery ajax, I don't think the `Anuncios` with `[HttpGet]` will be hit. Are you sure the provided example is correct?

Comment: Why are you creating a `POST` request to an action that is of type `GET`. The screenshot and the code you share are different.

Comment: also since `Anuncios` has multiple parameters isn't the object should different? (contains both filtro and pg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved removing  [ClaimsAuthorize("Admin", "")]